# Problems importing numpy into IPython notebook

Tags: numpy, ipython, enthought, canopy

Having some errors when attempting to run import numpy as np inside the IPython notebook environment. I assume that the Enthought Canopy package is borked, any tips would be much appreciated!

```
    ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-140a5caba752> in <module>()
----> 1 import numpy as np
      2 import scipy
      3 import matplotlib as mpl

/Users/iMacHome/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc in <module>()
    141         return loader(*packages, **options)
    142 
--> 143     import add_newdocs
    144     __all__ = ['add_newdocs']
    145 

/Users/iMacHome/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py in <module>()
      7 #       core/fromnumeric.py, core/defmatrix.py up-to-date.
      8 
----> 9 from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
     10 
     11 ###############################################################################
```

Comment: re-install?  Is that the full back trace? It looks trunacted to me.

Answer (score 0):

Reset your Canopy Python User environment by deleting `/Users/iMacHome/Library/Enthought/`, and restarting the Canopy GUI (to re-initialize the environment), then try again. If that doesn't do it, consider the possibility that you are cross-linking with another Python installation. To test this, what is your `sys.prefix` and `sys.path` in ipython?